# How does the Standard dictate the calls to A::operator int() in the code below?

Tags: c++, c++11, language-lawyer

`A::operator int()` is called in the code below according to the comments in the program. I think I have a good feeling what's happening here. But I'd like to know more precisely how does the Standard support those calls? I know that this kind of (implicit) operator is invoked in copy-initializations, which doesn't seem to be the case here.

```
#include <iostream>

class A {
    int i;
public:
    A(int j) : i(j){ std::cout << "constructor\n";  }
    A& operator=(int j) { std::cout << "operator =\n"; i = j; return *this; }
    A& operator+=(const A& rhs) { i += rhs.i; return *this; }
    const A operator+(const A& rhs) const { return A(*this) += rhs; }
    A& operator-=(const A& rhs) { i -= rhs.i; return *this; }
    const A operator-(const A& rhs) const { return A(*this) -= rhs; }
    operator int() const { std::cout << "operator int()\n"; return i; }
};

int main()
{
    A a(1);                 //  Invokes constructor A(int), printing "constructor"
    A b(2);                 //  Idem
    A c = a + b;            //  Invokes a.operator+(b) followed by a call to the default copy constructor which copies
                            //  the object referenced by the return of a + b into c.
    std::cout << c << '\n'; //  operator int() is called to convert the object c into an int, printing "operator int()"
                            //  followed by the number 3.
    c = a - b;              //  Invokes a.operator-(b) followed by a call to the default assignment operator which
                            //  copies the object referenced by the return of a - b into c.

    std::cout << c << '\n'; //  operator int() is called to convert the object c into an int, printing "operator int()"
                            //  followed by the number -1.

    c = (a - b) * c;        //  Invokes a.operator-(b) followed by two calls to operator int(), one to convert the
                            //  result of a - b into an int and another to convert c into an int. Finally the special
                            //  assignment operator, operator=(int) is called to assign the int resultant from the
                            //  expression (a - b) * c to the object c, printing "operator =".
}
```

Comment: For each "function call", the compiler makes a list of functions that are viable with one "user conversion" (that includes constructors and conversion operators), and if there's one match it calls that.  Otherwise it has a compiler error.  What's the question here?  What did you _expect_ would happen?

Comment: Also, I see at least one incorrect statement in the comments, where `c` is constructed.

Comment: Ah, the `(a-b)*c` line does hit upon a more complex case, that some function calls are "better" than others, I had missed that.  So you're asking how the compiler decides which functions are the "best" match for a parameter set?  That answer is actually surprisingly complicated :P

Comment: It would take too long to enumerate all the paragraphs in the standard required to interpret the expressions you've given. §13.3 in C++11 deals with overload resolution, so start there.

Comment: I think [over.match.copy] is largely responsible for conversions that appear due to function calls.

Comment: [over.match.oper] and [over.built] describe the conversions when using built-in operators.

Comment: *" I know that this kind of (implicit) operator is invoked in copy-initializations, which doesn't seem to be the case here."* Argument passing (by value) *invokes* copy-initialization. [dcl.init]/14

Comment: @dyp I think you got the correct answer. More precisely §13.3.1.2/2 answers exactly what I was looking for. It's hard for me to understand why this is so complicated, as was said above by other people!! If you care to give me an answer on those terms, I'll be glad to accept it. Thanks.

Comment: I was mistaken above on my comment to `dyp`. §13.3.1.2/2 doesn't explain the use of `operator int()` in the expressions `std::cout << c << '\n'` in the code. For those who might be interested, I obtained an excellent answer here ( http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/vstudio/en-US/0bad8490-e114-4bbc-9d98-850b570c5c4b/what-does-the-standard-say-about-the-use-of-operator-int-in-the-code-below?forum=vcgeneral ).